# Как сделать подмену двух номеров на сайте

Tags: javascript

Как сделать подмену двух номеров на сайте используя динамический коллтрекинг Mango Office?

Answer (score -1):

Для подмены номеров необходимо добавить следующий код на Ваш сайт.

```js
mgo({
    calltracking: { 
        id: 12345,
        elements: [
            {selector: '#some-element'},
            {selector: '.some-other-element'}
        ],
    }
});
```